# Javascript - Filter a nested arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to filter the below nested array. How do you filter the array by status, sales_rep and account_manager or by either status, sales_rep or account_manager using JavaScript and then return the filtered array.

I am from a python background.

```
[
{"account_manager":"Account Manager 1",
    "Accounts":[
        {
            "customer":"Customer 1",
            "Orders":[
                {
                    "order_no":"001",
                    "Services":[
                        {
                            "service_id":"001",
                            "sales_rep":"John Doe",
                            "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 1",
                            "status":"Provisioning - On Hold",
                        },
                        {
                            "service_id":"002",
                            "sales_rep":"Jane Doe",
                            "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 2",
                            "status":"Provisioning - Delay",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
    {
        "account_manager":"Account Manager 2",
        "Accounts":[
            {"customer":"Customer 2",
                "Orders":[
                    {
                        "order_no":"002",
                        "Services":[
                            {
                                "service_id":"003",
                                "sales_rep":"James Doe",
                                "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 3",
                                "status":"Provisioning - Delay",
                            },
                            {
                                "service_id":"003",
                                "sales_rep":"Mary Doe",
                                "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 1",
                                "status":"Provisioning - On Time (Low Risk)",
                            },
                            {
                                "service_id":"003",
                                "sales_rep":"Joey Doe",
                                "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 3",
                                "status":"Provisioning - On Time (High Risk)",
                            },

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Expected result if filtered by status "Provisioning - Delay" should be:

```
{"account_manager":"Account Manager 1",
        "Accounts":[
            {
                "customer":"Customer 1",
                "Orders":[
                    {
                        "order_no":"001",
                        "Services":[
                            {
                                "service_id":"002",
                                "sales_rep":"Jane Doe",
                                "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 2",
                                "status":"Provisioning - Delay",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "account_manager":"Account Manager 2",
        "Accounts":[
            {"customer":"Customer 2",
                "Orders":[
                    {
                        "order_no":"002",
                        "Services":[
                            {
                                "service_id":"003",
                                "sales_rep":"James Doe",
                                "order_project_manager":"Project Manager 3",
                                "status":"Provisioning - Delay",
                            },

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: did you try to solve it share the code with us please or if you can put an example of the expected result?

Comment: Hi @MoufeedJuboqji, Thank you for your comment. I added the expected result in my original question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/f7guyzk2/

```js
function filter(status, inputData) {
  const filterServices = (order) => {
    return {
      ...order,
      Services: order.Services.filter((service) => service.status === status),
    };
  };
  const filterOrders = (account) => {
    return {
      ...account,
      Orders: account.Orders.map(filterServices).filter(
        (order) => order.Services.length > 0
      ),
    };
  };
  const filterAccounts = (item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      Accounts: item.Accounts.map(filterOrders).filter(
        (account) => account.Orders.length > 0
      ),
    };
  };

  return inputData
    .map(filterAccounts)
    .filter((item) => item.Accounts.length > 0);
}

const res = filter("Provisioning - Delay", data /* Here put your data */);
```